# Nodejs does not receive a response object from SQL Server Insert. recordsets are undefined

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, asynchronous

I created a simple function that adds a person into a SQL Server table. The transaction works, and the data gets added to the db, but the response from the database after insertion is not returning the body of the inserted object.

The function:

```
async function addPerson(person) {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config)
        let newPerson = await pool.request()
            .input('name', sql.VarChar, person.name)
            .input('last', sql.VarChar, person.last)
            .input('age', sql.Int, person.age)
            .execute('InsertPerson')
        console.log(newPerson)
        return newPerson.recordsets;
    }
    catch {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

The route:

```
// insert person to table
router.route('/people').post((request, response) => {

    let person = { ...request.body }

    dboperations.addPerson(person).then(result => {
        response.status(201).json(result)
    })

})
```

SQL Server stored procedure `InsertPerson`:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertPerson
    @name VARCHAR(15),
    @last VARCHAR(15),
    @age INT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO person (name, last, age)
    VALUES (@name, @last, @age);

    RETURN 
END
```

I'm following along side this video tutorial, if it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uvy_BlgwfLI&list=PLM39hJgCef42hVok8ZRRE4LpLD-5bOxBh&index=37

Post method starts @ 31:30

My guess is it's related to how his stored procedure is made, but he doesn't show it and I'm having a hard time finding an example online of a procedure returning an inserted value.

Comment: Can't you use some ORM for this? Like Sequelize...i think it would help you a lot. Give it a look. It does exactly what you want in, like, two lines.

Comment: I was going to look into Sequelize right after going through this tutorial, I just wanted to get the basics. It just doesn't makes sense to me that his returns the object and mines doesn't, but I'm looking into the OUTPUT clause in sql server. If that doesn't work I'll just go with Sequelize.

Comment: I don't know if you're working on a side project. But if it is for a long date software, keep in mind that not only your database can change but its versions too. The good thing about using ORM is that you don't need to worry about communications with your database. I hope you achieve what you want man. Godspeed!

Comment: _but the response from the database after insertion is not returning the body of the inserted object._ Why would it? The stored procedure doesn't return anything other than the default return status, 0. Perhaps inside the stored procedure you mean to capture the scope_identity() value after the insert statement and then select that record to return to the caller?